# jQuery animate.css not working correctly on Firefox only

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, wordpress

I'm pretty much a novice at jQuery and i'm trying to use some animations which work fine except on Firefox.

I'm using the [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library and trying to use the animations for text captions on a slider.

I'm using the [Soliloquy](https://soliloquywp.com/) wordpress plugin slider.

The soliloquy slider adds a

```
.soliloquy-active-slide
```

to the currently active slide so i've added jQuery to add the animated class on the active slide:

```
jQuery('#caption-1').on('.soliloquy-id-8 .soliloquy-active-slide').addClass('animated slideInLeft');
```

The animation actually works when the first slide loads, but then stops working when the slider comes back round to the first slide.

Oddly this only happens on Firefox, in Chrome and Safari the animation keeps on running when it comes back to the first slider.

Odder still, the animation does work as intended firebug debugger is open.

I realise i haven't posted much code but I can provide more if needed.

Any help getting this working on Firefox would be great.

Cheers

Comment: jQuery `on` is used for attaching events. What are you attempting to do in that line of code?

Comment: I want the animation to fire when a slide becomes "the active slide"

Answer (score 0):

if you want the animation to occurred more than once, you need to remove the corresponding classes once the animation ended, as follow:

```
    jQuery('#yourElement').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('animated slideInLeft');
    });
```

and later you can add your desired classes once again...

Comment: thanks Jumpa, but I looked at this already. I don't want the animated class to be removed i just want it to be added to the caption only when the slide is active. I think the slider plugin uses jquery/ajax to add the `.soliloquy-active-slide` class to the currently displayed slide, which is when I went the animation class to be added to the caption.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot add/remove classes on a dynamically generated class like the "active-slide" class generated by the slider.

So I used an in-built action hook which seems to do the trick:

```
add_action( 'soliloquy_api_on_load', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\slide_in_left_onload' );
function slide_in_left_onload( $data ) {
  ob_start();
  ?>
  soliloquy_<?php echo $data['id']; ?>.find('.soliloquy-id-8 .soliloquy-caption #caption-1').addClass('animated slideInLeft').css('display','block');
  <?php
  echo ob_get_clean();
}

add_action( 'soliloquy_api_after_transition', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\slide_in_left' );
function slide_in_left( $data ) {
  ob_start();
  ?>
  soliloquy_<?php echo $data['id']; ?>.find('.soliloquy-id-8 .soliloquy-caption #caption-1').addClass('animated slideInLeft').css('display','block');
  <?php
  echo ob_get_clean();
}

add_action( 'soliloquy_api_before_transition', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\end_slide_animation' );
function end_slide_animation( $data ) {
  ob_start();
  ?>
  soliloquy_<?php echo $data['id']; ?>.find('.soliloquy-id-8 .soliloquy-caption #caption-1').removeClass('animated slideInLeft').css('display','none');
  <?php
  echo ob_get_clean();
}
```